# What is the most bandwidth efficient way to remotely access a Windows pc?

Tags: remote-desktop, bandwidth

I want to access my work computer from home(or vice versa). I live in a bandwidth constrained 3rd world country so RDP is too slow to be useful in most cases. Can anyone point me in the direction of doing this efficiently? I am comfortable with using command line utilities.

I would require complete control of the remote computer (administrator privileges/access to registry/ability to restart and reconnect).

If the solution is platform agnostic, it would be better but right now. I really need to connect 2 Windows pcs.

Comment: You'd imagine that RDP would be the best, no? Have you configured all your rdp options for minimal resource use? Low colours, small screen, etc

Comment: I'm currently using SSH instead since windows 10 has native support for it now(needs to be enabled in settings). RDP is painful to use even at lowest settings, one of the PCs i need to access is via a 2G mobile connection(50kbps avg)

Comment: I think you need to clarify what level of control you need over the remote machine?

Comment: @CaiusJard it says right there in the question(2nd para) but i'll repeat - I would require complete control of the remote computer (administrator privileges/access to registry/ability to restart and reconnect).

Comment: Sorry; you'd mentioned RDP which set me thinking that you need to use the GUI of the remote machine in some way. If all your work could be carried out using command line / file transfer etc and you have SSH working, what are you stil ltrying to achieve that SSH isn't providing

Comment: If you want to avoid using SSH you could also checkout PowerShell remoting. You probably shouldn't directly connect it to the internet. If it's really 50 kilo bit per second you're looking at 6.25 kilo byte per second. At that data rate doing anything that requires a graphical interface is going to be difficult.

Comment: @CaiusJard it is an older question, i forgot about it once i figured out the solution of using ssh, am writing up an answer now

Answer (score -1):

SSH would probably be the most efficient, but if you require GUI try https://remotedesktop.google.com/